# Django - Delete db entry when ForeignKey was deleted

Tags: django, api, rest

I am having trouble to solve this issue, even though I thought I understood the on_delete function.

I have a model called Project and a model called UserProject. In the Userproject I have two foreign Keys pointing to a User and a Project.

What I tried was to use on_delete = CASCADE on the project-Foreign Key. This seems to only affect the Project-field in the Userproject model. So when I delete a Project which also has Userproject entries, those don't get deleted. How could I achieve this?

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Project(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(db_column = 'db_ID', primary_key = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, default = None)
    descriptor = models.CharField(max_length = 1000, null = True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'projects'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name




class Userproject(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column = 'db_ID', primary_key = True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.SET_NULL, null = True)
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project', on_delete = models.CASCADE,default = 1, null = True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null = True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'UserProjects'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the bug. It was deleted for me. I've copied your code and run the shell:
> project_1 = Project.objects.create(name='project_1')
> user_project_1 = Userproject.objects.create(project=project_1)
> Userproject.objects.all()
# <QuerySet [<Userproject: project_1>]>
> project_1.delete()
> Userproject.objects.all()
# <QuerySet []>

Answer (score 0):

It seems you may be deleting the `project` attribute from the `Userproject` attribute, but not deleting the `Project` itself.  Try deleting a `Project` object from the admin panel, if there are associated cascade objects they should be displayed on the deletion confirmation page.

Since the `project` attribute can be set to null, this seems to describe the behavior you are seeing.  `CASCADE` is used here correctly based on what we can see.